# Bash script: for loop using a range in the form {0001..$n}

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, sequence

I'm trying to compare the first character of each line of a buttload of files with the format *filename.number.ext* where *number* is a 4-digit number (0001, 0015, 5403, etc). My script goes like this:

```
 n=$1
 awk '{print $1}' filename.0001.ext > temp1.dat
 for i in {0002..$n}
   do
     echo $i
     awk '{print $1}' filename.$i.ext > temp.dat
     diff temp1.dat temp.dat
   done
```

This works fine if, instead of an input, I use a fixed value for the number of files, like so:

```
 awk '{print $1}' filename.0001.ext > temp1.dat
 for i in {0002..0345}
   do
     echo $i
     awk '{print $1}' filename.$i.ext > temp.dat
     diff temp1.dat temp.dat
   done
```

However, with the first version if I input 0345 for example, the shell returns

```
 $ myscript.sh 0345
 {0002..0345}
 awk: cannot open filename.{0002..0345}.ext (No such file or directory)
```

I'm a little lost here. I insist on using `{0002..0345}` over `seq` because all the file numbers have a fixed length of 4.

Answer (score 2):

A variable cannot be used in [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion). You need to use C-style for loop:

```
for (( i = 0002; i <= $n; i++ )); do
    true  # do whatever
done
```

See [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs) for details.

Comment: Or of course you can use `seq`.

Comment: Thank you, but then how do I make sure that my indices are in a 4-digit form?

Comment: @Régence Use `printf %04d $i` or `for i in $(seq -w 2 n)`.

Comment: Agree that `seq -w` is a good way to go. Unfortunately, it does not allow you specifically to set the padding, so if this _were_ an issue you can combine the two with `xargs`, e.g. `seq 2 9 | xargs printf "%04d\n"`

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I solved my problem by using `for i in {0002..9999}` and putting a `break` after n iterations. Not very elegant but it works well for my purpose.